# What is the correct type annotation for bot3.client(service)

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, python-typing

With boto3 we can create a client for any service of our choice. For example,

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
```

Then if we check the type of the returned object,

```
print(type(client))
<class 'botocore.client.S3'>
```

But since there is no `botocore.client.S3` (since it is dynamically created), how do we strongly type the client?

The closest I can think of is `botocore.client.BaseClient` as shown below, which is far from `S3` type.

```
from botocore.client import BaseClient
client: BaseClient = boto3.client('s3')
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [**mypy-boto3**](https://pypi.org/project/mypy-boto3/):

```py
import boto3
from mypy_boto3_s3 import S3Client
from typing_extensions import reveal_type


def foo(client: S3Client):
    ...


s3_client = boto3.client("s3")

reveal_type(s3_client)  # revealed type is S3Client

foo(s3_client)  # OK!
```